# Non Visual Studio F# IDE

Tags: ide, f#

Does anyone know of an IDE for F# development that does not involve me shelling out $300? I will gladly move to F# VS Express if they ever release one, but spending money to just get started with a new language is not in my budget.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243488/f-and-visual-studio-2010-express-edition, http://talbottcrowell.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/three-free-ways-to-develop-in-f-3-0/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx2008/products/bb933751.aspx

Visual Studio Shell - Free, and F# supports it out of the box.

(edited)
http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2008/04/04/tackling-the-f-productization.aspx

Theres a link talking about using the Shell and such too

Answer (score 16):

It looks like the latest beta version of [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/#SharpDevelop30) (3.0) has F# support. SharpDevelop is an open source IDE, something of a Visual Studio clone. I used it years ago when I was somewhere too cheap to buy Visual Studio.

Answer (score 9):

[Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) / [Xamarin Studio](https://www.xamarin.com/studio) is a free ide compatible with .net and mono envoriments

Comment: F# support in Monodevelop is in place and improving fast! https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/fsharp-opensource

Answer (score 5):

LinqPad 4.0 has the support for F#.
http://www.linqpad.net/Beta.aspx

Answer (score 2):

start a WebsiteSpark microsoft programm. It is free and for three years you will have access to latest version of visual studio professional. Glad I found it three years ago...

[here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/websitespark/) the link

this is the description of my company just to show you :

*freelance without any customer just to learn new stuff ;)*