# F# and Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, f#

Is there any way to work with F# on Visual Studio 2010 Expression Edition. I am having Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition Beta 2.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There won't be Visual F# Express but you can use the free Visual Studio Shell (wich is available for 2008 and 2010) with F#. It works perfectly for 2008 but I have not tested it with 2010.

**Update:**

The release of F# 2.0 works with the 2010 Integrated shell as well; see Don Syme's blog post ["Announcing the F# 2.0 Free Tools Update"](https://web.archive.org/web/20140908064140/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/08/17/announcing-the-f-2-0-free-tools-for-net-4-0.aspx).

**Update:**
[Visual F# tools 3.1.1 now support VS Express for Desktop and VS Express for Web](https://web.archive.org/web/20151231223557/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2014/01/22/announcing-visual-f-3-1-1-and-support-for-desktop-express.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, there are no plans to include an F# Express edition for Visual Studio 2010.  The express editions for 2010 are:

- Visual Basic 2010 Express
- Visual Web Developer 2010 Express
- Visual C# 2010 Express
- Visual C++ 2010 Express

[Source of above.](http://talbottc.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!A6E0DA836D488CA6!485.entry)

Comment: Also see this: http://talbottc.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!A6E0DA836D488CA6!485.entry

Comment: @Richard - Thanks. Much better reference as it also mentioned the future

Answer (score 2):

While F# is not included in VS2010 Express, it appears to be supported in VS2012 Express Web Edition.

> Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web ... is a free
>   development environment that programmers can use to build projects
>   such as ASP.NET applications and Windows Azure cloud services. This F#
>   Tools release adds in F# 3.0 components, such as the F# 3.0 compiler,
>   F# Interactive, IDE support, and new F# features such as type
>   providers and query expressions.

- [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/09/12/announcing-the-release-of-f-tools-for-visual-studio-express-2012-for-web.aspx)

Comment: I am using F# in VS2010 just fine - I believe it is included in the default install.

Comment: My mistake, I meant VS2010 Express. Fixed.